# Update user information

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, updates

Tried this for updating user information , only phone number but it's not getting update.

```
router.post('/edit', checkAuth, function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.userData.userId)
    User.update({_id: req.userData.userId}, {$set:req.userData.phoneNo}, function (err){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.status(200).send(req.userData);
    });
});
```

My **user controller** const mongoose = require ('mongoose');

```
const User = mongoose.model('User');

module.exports.register = (req, res, next) =>{  

    var user = new User();
    user.fullName = req.body.fullName;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
    user.save((err, doc) =>{
        if(!err)
            res.send(doc);
        else{
            if (err.code == 11000)
                    res.status(422).send(["Entered duplicate email address. Please check"]);
            else
            return next(err);
            }
    });
}
```

And then I am authenticating  by passing jwt on this field
`phoneNo: user[0].phoneNumber`

The auth-token verifies and decode the fields

```
const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY)
        req.userData = decoded;
```

Update is not working and getting error message `Invalid atomic update value for $set. Expected an object, received string` .

Comment: Can you post the `User` class/function definition?

Comment: @Mortz I have updated my user controller

Comment: could you print phoneNo & check its data type

Comment: also check the datatype of decoded userData

Comment: @kRiZ Yes I can print `phoneNo`  of string

Comment: Could you please confirm Phone Number field is defined as String in Mongoose schema or mongodb

Comment: I think you need to pass the phone number as `User.update({_id: req.userData.userId}, {$set: {phoneNumber: req.userData.phoneNo}}, ...)`

Comment: @kRiZ yes it is defined. I have define in user.model `phoneNumber : {
    type: String,
    required: "Reqired for further contact.Can't be empty"
    }`

Comment: @Mortz I did , still not getting update.

Comment: you are missing $set:{phoneNo:req.data.phone}

Comment: @WhoAmI - still the same error?

Comment: @Mortz I am not getting any error now , but the field is not getting updated yet.

Comment: Please see here - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update
##Be careful to not use an existing model instance for the update clause (this won't work and can cause weird behavior like infinite loops). Also, ensure that the update clause does not have an _id property, which causes Mongo to return a "Mod on _id not allowed" error.##

Comment: @Mortz I have removed `_id: req.userData.userId` . But didn't get exactly.

Comment: @WhoAmI - I am not sure of this - but maybe you should try to `exec` the update - `User.update({_id: req.userData.userId}, {$set: {phoneNumber: req.userData.phoneNo}}, ...).exec()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you should use `PATCH`-method - because you are updating only one item in existed object, in `body` you should send `id` of user and new value of certain value. If you use `mongoose` you can try it 
`User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, updatedItem, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
                if (err) return res.send(err.message)
                if (doc) return res.send(doc);
            })`

`const id = req.body._id;`, if you dont use mongoose you should try `findAndModify` method

Comment: `doc` - it is updated value,
`updatedItem`  - it is - `req.body`

Comment: why this ? `const id = req.body._id` ; I am already getting value of _id from decoded js file in `req.userData.userId`. So i guess it was not necessary like this . And what if I want to update multiple items ? When I am editing multiple items it is getting changed even  with  `findOneAndUpdate`

Comment: you can send multiple items and it will be updated - if you are about it - `{phoneNumber: 123, fullName:'Bill'}`

Comment: Thanks for the information . Items in mongo db is getting updated but the data is not responding with updated value in profile data . So do I always have to login and see the updated value. Is there any method to check instant through server side?

Comment: Just want to know, what I was missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
User.update({_id: req.userData.userId}, {$set:req.userData.phoneNo}
```

Correct code:

```
User.update({_id: req.userData.userId}, {$set:{phoneNumber:req.userData.phoneNo}}
```

Try this method:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.userData.userId, { $set:{phoneNumber:req.userData.phoneNo}}, { new: true }, function (err, user) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  res.send(user);
});
```

Comment: I did make the correction , but still  the field is not getting updated.

Comment: No the error is gone, but the respond data is same. No update

Comment: can you try findByIdAndUpdate method?

Comment: tried , not updating , Am I passing correct body object `{
 "phoneNumber": "11111111"
}` ?

Comment: should be {phoneNo: "11111111"}

Comment: can you just try updating the document with hardcoded value.

Comment: I have tried this  `User.updateOne(req.userData.userId, {$set: { phoneNumber: req.userData.phoneNo}}, { new: true }, function (err, userData){ ..` and it is showing this `message:
 'Parameter "filter" to updateOne() must be an object, got 5c34772a22f98e31801e8252',
name: 'ObjectParameterError' }` as error message

Comment: if you are using updateOne, it should be _id:req.userData.userId

Comment: It's been depreciated . got message `findAndUpdate is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate`. Still no success

Comment: dude.. which method you are using now?

Comment: I  am using `findOneAndUpdate` method.